# Invalid JSON character

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I have a JSON that returned from my controller in C#.

A specific field have the character `"\"` in the text, as the next example:

```html
[{
      "DTH_INCLUI_LOG": "2016-01-13T10:58:32",
      "COD_IDENT_USUAR": "AC43771",
      "COD_IDENT_HOST": "ACESITA\ACE14802",
      "DSC_ALTERACAO": "Aço Histórico I1033 foi excluído da Aplicação 006 - Calderaria/Tanques e Aço I1017.",
      "VLR_ANTIGO": "I1033",
      "VLR_NOVO": " ",
      "SQ_LOG_ALTER": 3695.0
    }]
```

When I execute `JSON.Parse` method, I get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A
```

```js
@model string

var temp = '@Html.Raw(Model)';
resultado = JSON.parse(temp);
```

Comment: Could you please paste the string itself instead of an already parsed JSON so we can investigate what exactly is happening?

Comment: Why  you converting to parse json it is already in parse state

Comment: I edited with a simple code. See if it's is enought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `"ACESITA\ACE14802"` isn't a valid JSON value. (As described in the [RFC [Section 7. Strings]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-7))

If you have control over the generation of this string then ensure that you correctly escape the '' so it becomes '\\'. If you don't have control then unfortunately you won't be able to use any parser that expects a valid JSON string.